# CUDA 10.1 & Mac OS X 10.13.6 Driver Version Insufficient

Tags: cuda

I installed all the CUDA packages, drivers, samples, and cuDNN.

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:14:47_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
:deviceQuery$ ./devicequery
./devicequery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
deviceQuery$
```

Any idea why? Every driver, and everything else I have is fully up to date, and I have checked the drivers to see if they match up.

Comment: Have you tried both the built-in Apple graphics drivers & Nvidia's own web driver? [I don't have any Mac here with NVidia, all AMD, so I can't actually test anything.] Also - what Mac, what GPU?

Comment: Mac, Geforce Gigabyte 1050 TI

Comment: Mac Pro then? presumably with a non-flashed card [confirmation on that is if you don't see the boot screen until login appears] I'd try the web drivers [you din't say which you'd tried] MacVidCards is the single best source of info on which drivers to use with which OS - http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html

Comment: I mean Cuda drivers, and i'm using the NVIDIA Web Drivers right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it is solved by installing this.

https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/nvidia-update